# The entity type LogEntry is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: mysql, code-first, dbcontext

I'm working to hook in BitFactory.Logging into my application.
My one change is that I am posting the LogEvent to my MySQL database.
Running Code First, EF 4.1.

I wrote a custom db logger as follows:

```
public class DBLogger : Logger
{
    protected override bool DoLog(LogEntry aLogEntry)
    {
        _db.Add(aLogEntry);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
    private static IDbContext _db = new MyDB();
    public static IDbContext db
    {
        get { return _db; }
    }
}
```

I have the following class:

```
public class LEntry
{
    public virtual LogEntry logEntry { get; set; }
}
```

}

I have the following IDbContext:

```
public interface IDbContext
{

    IQueryable<LEntry> LEntries { get; }
    int SaveChanges();
    T Attach<T>(T entity) where T : class;
    T Add<T>(T entity) where T : class;
    T Delete<T>(T entity) where T : class;
}
```

and the following

```
public class MyDB : DbContext, IDbContext
{
    public DbSet<LEntry> LEntries { get; set; }

    IQueryable<LEntry> IDbContext.LEntries
    {
        get { return LEntries; }
    }

    int IDbContext.SaveChanges()
    {
        return SaveChanges();
    }

    T IDbContext.Add<T>(T entity) 
    {
        return Set<T>().Add(entity);
    }

    T IDbContext.Delete<T>(T entity) 
    {
        return Set<T>().Remove(entity);            
    }

    T IDbContext.Attach<T>(T entity)
    {                      
        var entry = Entry(entity);
        entry.State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
        return entity;
    }
}
```

When I run the code, I get the following error:

"System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'LEntry' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType."

If I change my LEntry class to

```
public class LEntry
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual LogEntry logEntry { get; set; }
}
```

}

and run, I get the following error:

"The type 'LogEntry' is mapped as a complex type. The Set method, DbSet objects, and DbEntityEntry objects can only be used with entity types, not complex types."

If I change LEntry to be ComplexType as follows:

```
[ComplexType]
public class LEntry
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual LogEntry logEntry { get; set; }
}
```

I then get the following error:

"The type 'MyDB.Models.LEntry' has already been configured as an entity type. It cannot be reconfigured as a complex type."

which is thrown on the

```
    T IDbContext.Add<T>(T entity) 
    {
        return Set<T>().Add(entity);
    }
```

block.

All I am trying to do is on the DoLog method post to my MySQL database.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. What is the purpose of the LEntry class? And what does your LogEntry class look like?